# My (correct) Hashmap returns null when accessed from my mainclass - (beginner)

Tags: java, null, hashmap

```
public class Board {
    public HashMap<String, String> spelMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public String[] mapping =
        {
                ""+spelMap.get("A")+"-----------"+spelMap.get("B")+"-----------"+spelMap.get("C")+"", 
                "|           |           |",
                "|   "+spelMap.get("D")+"-------"+spelMap.get("E")+"-------"+spelMap.get("F")+"   |",
                "|   |       |       |   |",
                "|   |   "+spelMap.get("G")+"---"+spelMap.get("H")+"---"+spelMap.get("I")+"   |   |",
                "|   |   |       |   |   |",
                ""+spelMap.get("J")+"---"+spelMap.get("K")+"---"+spelMap.get("L")+"       "+spelMap.get("M")+"---"+spelMap.get("N")+"---"+spelMap.get("O")+"",
                "|   |   |       |   |   |",
                "|   |   "+spelMap.get("P")+"---"+spelMap.get("Q")+"---"+spelMap.get("R")+"   |   |",
                "|   |       |       |   |",
                "|   "+spelMap.get("S")+"-------"+spelMap.get("T")+"-------"+spelMap.get("U")+"   |",
                "|           |           |",
                ""+spelMap.get("V")+"-----------"+spelMap.get("W")+"-----------"+spelMap.get("X")+""
        };
    Board(){

        spelMap.put("A", ".");
        spelMap.put("B", ".");
        spelMap.put("C", ".");
        spelMap.put("D", ".");
        spelMap.put("E", ".");
        spelMap.put("F", ".");
        spelMap.put("G", ".");
        spelMap.put("H", ".");
        spelMap.put("I", ".");
        spelMap.put("J", ".");
        spelMap.put("K", ".");
        spelMap.put("L", ".");
        spelMap.put("M", ".");
        spelMap.put("N", ".");
        spelMap.put("O", ".");
        spelMap.put("P", ".");
        spelMap.put("Q", ".");
        spelMap.put("R", ".");
        spelMap.put("S", ".");
        spelMap.put("T", ".");
        spelMap.put("U", ".");
        spelMap.put("V", ".");
        spelMap.put("W", ".");
        spelMap.put("X", ".");
    }
```

// this is what is in my mainclass to access the hashmap.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Board bord = new Board();

        for(int i=0; i < bord.mapping.length; i++){
            System.out.println(bord.mapping[i]);
        }
```

// this is what it returns when compiled

```
null-----------null-----------null

|           |           |

|   null-------null-------null   |

|   |       |       |   |

|   |   null---null---null   |   |
|   |   |       |   |   |
null---null---null       null---null---null
|   |   |       |   |   |
|   |   null---null---null   |   |
|   |       |       |   |
|   null-------null-------null   |
|           |           |
null-----------null-----------null
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your code as follows. put `mapping` array inside a method. then this will works fine.

```
public class Board {
public HashMap<String, String> spelMap = new HashMap<String, String>();

Board() {
    spelMap.put("A", ".");
    spelMap.put("B", ".");
    spelMap.put("C", ".");
    spelMap.put("D", ".");
    spelMap.put("E", ".");
    spelMap.put("F", ".");
    spelMap.put("G", ".");
    spelMap.put("H", ".");
    spelMap.put("I", ".");
    spelMap.put("J", ".");
    spelMap.put("K", ".");
    spelMap.put("L", ".");
    spelMap.put("M", ".");
    spelMap.put("N", ".");
    spelMap.put("O", ".");
    spelMap.put("P", ".");
    spelMap.put("Q", ".");
    spelMap.put("R", ".");
    spelMap.put("S", ".");
    spelMap.put("T", ".");
    spelMap.put("U", ".");
    spelMap.put("V", ".");
    spelMap.put("W", ".");
    spelMap.put("X", ".");

}

public String[] postMethod() {
    return new String[]
            {
                    "" + spelMap.get("A") + "-----------" + spelMap.get("B") + "-----------" + spelMap.get("C") + "",
                    "|           |           |",
                    "|   " + spelMap.get("D") + "-------" + spelMap.get("E") + "-------" + spelMap.get("F") + "   |",
                    "|   |       |       |   |",
                    "|   |   " + spelMap.get("G") + "---" + spelMap.get("H") + "---" + spelMap.get("I") + "   |   |",
                    "|   |   |       |   |   |",
                    "" + spelMap.get("J") + "---" + spelMap.get("K") + "---" + spelMap.get("L") + "       " + spelMap.get("M") + "---" + spelMap.get("N") + "---" + spelMap.get("O") + "",
                    "|   |   |       |   |   |",
                    "|   |   " + spelMap.get("P") + "---" + spelMap.get("Q") + "---" + spelMap.get("R") + "   |   |",
                    "|   |       |       |   |",
                    "|   " + spelMap.get("S") + "-------" + spelMap.get("T") + "-------" + spelMap.get("U") + "   |",
                    "|           |           |",
                    "" + spelMap.get("V") + "-----------" + spelMap.get("W") + "-----------" + spelMap.get("X") + ""
            };
    }

}
```

Then main themod

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Board bord = new Board();

    for(int i=0; i < bord.postMethod().length; i++){
        System.out.println(bord.postMethod()[i]);
    }
}
```

Now out put

```
.-----------.-----------.
|           |           |
|   .-------.-------.   |
|   |       |       |   |
|   |   .---.---.   |   |
|   |   |       |   |   |
.---.---.       .---.---.
|   |   |       |   |   |
|   |   .---.---.   |   |
|   |       |       |   |
|   .-------.-------.   |
|           |           |
.-----------.-----------.
```

In this case your `HashMap` only access just after the initialize. So then `HashMap` now contains with values.

Comment: thank you, this worked! Can you explain to me why it worked, and why my approach did not work?

Comment: @Ruben In your case the moment you are initializing `String` array is empty. You can check this my putting `debug` point in `main()` too. So you are getting all `null`. But in this case, we are accessing array after initialize. So now you will have mapped value for the `key`. please leave a comment if you did not get my point clear.

Comment: I think I understand. I don't understand why it has to become a method to work, is there an easy way to explain this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access the HashMap entries before you've put them in there. Also, keep in mind that you can only create an array like that when you first initialize it. This for example works though:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Board {
public static HashMap<String, String> spelMap;
public static String[] mapping;

public Board() {
    spelMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    spelMap.put("A", ".");
    spelMap.put("B", ".");
    spelMap.put("C", ".");
    spelMap.put("D", ".");
    spelMap.put("E", ".");
    spelMap.put("F", ".");
    spelMap.put("G", ".");
    spelMap.put("H", ".");
    spelMap.put("I", ".");
    spelMap.put("J", ".");
    spelMap.put("K", ".");
    spelMap.put("L", ".");
    spelMap.put("M", ".");
    spelMap.put("N", ".");
    spelMap.put("O", ".");
    spelMap.put("P", ".");
    spelMap.put("Q", ".");
    spelMap.put("R", ".");
    spelMap.put("S", ".");
    spelMap.put("T", ".");
    spelMap.put("U", ".");
    spelMap.put("V", ".");
    spelMap.put("W", ".");
    spelMap.put("X", ".");

}

public static void main(String args[]) {

    Board board = new Board();

    String[] mapping = {
            "" + spelMap.get("A") + "-----------" + spelMap.get("B")
                    + "-----------" + spelMap.get("C") + "",
            "|           |           |",
            "|   " + spelMap.get("D") + "-------" + spelMap.get("E")
                    + "-------" + spelMap.get("F") + "   |",
            "|   |       |       |   |",
            "|   |   " + spelMap.get("G") + "---" + spelMap.get("H")
                    + "---" + spelMap.get("I") + "   |   |",
            "|   |   |       |   |   |",
            "" + spelMap.get("J") + "---" + spelMap.get("K") + "---"
                    + spelMap.get("L") + "       " + spelMap.get("M")
                    + "---" + spelMap.get("N") + "---" + spelMap.get("O")
                    + "",
            "|   |   |       |   |   |",
            "|   |   " + spelMap.get("P") + "---" + spelMap.get("Q")
                    + "---" + spelMap.get("R") + "   |   |",
            "|   |       |       |   |",
            "|   " + spelMap.get("S") + "-------" + spelMap.get("T")
                    + "-------" + spelMap.get("U") + "   |",
            "|           |           |",
            "" + spelMap.get("V") + "-----------" + spelMap.get("W")
                    + "-----------" + spelMap.get("X") + "" };
    board.mapping = mapping;

    for(int i=0; i < board.mapping.length; i++){
        System.out.println(board.mapping[i]);
    }

}
}
```

You could set up a getter and a setter method for the Board class that accepts a "mapping" and sets the value of the mapping variable in the class.

Comment: i've exchanged the positions of the "mapping" and the Board(), unfortunately it still returns null

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because

*The body of each instance initializer is inserted at the beginning of every constructor for the class, along with any field initialization expressions.*

See this [tutorial](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java-ent/jnut/ch03_02.htm) section 3.2.4.1